# lme4 variance of predictions

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, lme4-nlme

I want to calculate standard errors of predicted outcomes from
a mixed-effects model estimated via lme4's glmer function.

Since my question is quite basic, I use a sloppy notation and hope that it becomes clear nevertheless. Let $X$ denote the design-matrix for the fixed effects $\beta$, $Z$ the design-matrix for the random effects $\Gamma$

So the model looks like this:
$y = X\beta + Z\Gamma + \varepsilon\quad \text{with } \varepsilon \sim(0,\sigma^2) $

I want to do the following calculations:

$\hat{Var_1} = X\hat{Cov(\beta)}X^T$

$\hat{Var_2} = X\hat{Cov(\beta)}X^T + Z\hat{Cov(\Gamma)}Z^T$

$\hat{Var_3} = X\hat{Cov(\beta)}X^T + Z\hat{Cov(\Gamma)}Z^T + \hat{\sigma^2}$

There are many similar questions in the web, and most of the answer refer to http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#predconf
I read the entry in the faq but the following questions remain unresolved:

1. Is there a simple way how to obtain the matrix $Z$?
   Something similar to

   ```
   X <- model.matrix(terms(model_name))
   ```
2. Which of the three Variance estimators is conceptually most appropriate, if I want to quantify the uncertainty of the model prediction for a population unit of which we do not know z?

$\hat{Var_1}$ seems reasonable, since it doesn't depend on $z$. But one might also think about (a possibly weighted) mean of $\hat{Var_2}$.

Thanks!

Comment: `t(getME(fitted_model,"Zt"))` ?

Comment: @BenBolker     I'm looking for a matrix whose columns correspond to the random effects. For example if the model had a random intercept only, the returned matrix should be a Nx1-Matrix of ones. If it also contained a random effect for some variable, this variable should form the second column of my matrix etc. I'm aware that that's an easy manual task, but the analogy to the model.matrix X for the fixed effect made me assume, that there's some shortcut for the random effect model matrix, too.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the Z matrix is? from `?getME`:  `Zt: transpose of random-effects model matrix.  Note that the structure of ‘Zt’ has changed since ‘lme4.0’; to get a backward-compatible structure, use
'do.call(Matrix::rBind,getME(.,"Ztlist"))’`

Comment: Maybe i got some concepts wrong but with $p$ random effects, I'd expect an $N \times p$ matrix such that $Z\hat{Cov(\Gamma)}Z^T$, with $\hat{Cov(\Gamma)}$ being `VarCorr(mm1)$group`, can be calculated. The $Z$ you suppose is (in my example) $N \times (p * k)$ with $k$ being the number of groups.